# Can't type a less than or greater than

Tags: windows, keyboard

I've had this happen before, a reboot always fixes it.  This time it won't, though.  I get a comma or a period, it's like I didn't press the shift key.  Trying to write code without those keys is quite a pain.

Comment: Does a different keyboard fix the issue?

Comment: @Steven Thank you!  I was looking all over through Windows settings, your comment made me try unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in again.  <<Hallelujah>>

Answer (score 2):

> it's like I didn't press the shift key

This answer assumes that it is like that for **all** keys: i.e., you try to get an <kbd>A</kbd>, you get an <kbd>a</kbd>, and so on; the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key **is really (temporarily) not working**.

---

Sometimes Windows (but I had this happen to me on Linux Desktop, OpenSuSE 13.2 too) seems to "lose track" of the status of *some* control key. For me it is usually the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key or the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key that either goes unresponsive or behaves as if it was pressed - for example <kbd>F4</kbd> alone closes an application, just as if I had pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

If we were back in the '90s I'd say it's the result of messing with the i8042 chip [A20 control line](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/A20.html), a sad kludge devised in the low Middle Ages to access the high memory area below 1 MB RAM; [when the PC was really busy, it lost track](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9448). But *I believe* that the whole mess nowadays is actually emulated, and has been for a while. Maybe I'm wrong and [the need to handle the blasted thing with care is still with us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825241/are-so-many-keyboard-controller-wait-calls-needed-when-enabling-the-a20-gate), for the symptoms are eerily similar.

And the resolution (for me at least) is also eerily similar - just start rapidly poking at <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> at random, no more than four times each to prevent the [Accessibility prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StickyKeys) from activating. Some suggest trying [pressing the keys together](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/195718-how-to-reset-a-keyboard-and-mouse-when-odd-problems-happen-with-them), but I never needed to do that.

This also worked on a laptop with Windows XP and no detachable keyboard, that got upgraded to Windows 7 Professional and occasionally - maybe once a month, same as with XP - exhibits the same symptoms.

Sure enough, as you discovered thanks to Steven's suggestion, unplugging and re-plugging the keyboard (where possible) *will* trigger a keyboard reset with *much* greater certainty.

Comment: Your fix applies to Windows getting confused about what keys are down--over the years I've done it many, many times.  One quick press of all shift, ctrl & alt keys clears the problem--all at once doesn't matter but is faster than one at a time.  However, this was a hardware issue, cleared by unplugging my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your keyboard layout settings in windows are not right. You need to change the setting in windows to be set the the standard US keyboard layout.